Craft5 -> CP: Field groups are gone?
Just wondering: https://craft5.ddev.site/admin/settings/fields -> there are no field groups anymore?
That's a loss ... :(

At the moment they are gone (and I miss them, too). You could upvote https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/14600
